# js: promises inside a while- true loop

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, youtube-api

I am having some difficulties with retrieving all data from youtube playlist. Here is my code:

```
function getApiUrl(nextPageToken) {
    return '<api_url>' + '&playlistId=' + '<playlistId>' + (nextPageToken !== null ? '&pageToken=' + nextPageToken : '');
}

function getPlaylist() {
    var titles = [],
        nextPageToken = null,
        url = getApiUrl(null);

    while(true) {
        // returns new Promise(...)
        doRequest(url).then(data => {
            // process data : push items to titles array
            nextPageToken = data.nextPageToken;
        });

        if (nextPageToken === undefined) {
            break;
        }

        url = getApiUrl(nextPageToken);
    }

    // returns empty array
    return titles;
}
```

Trying to break the loop inside the data handler leads to `SyntaxError: Illegal break statement`

Comment: Using an infinite loop that isn't related to a generator function typically isn't a good idea. What you should do here is set a variable to true, and when `nextPageToken === undefined`, set the variable to false. That will stop the loop

Comment: @SterlingArcher still does not solve the problem with the empty array

Comment: @SterlingArcher wouldn't that not work since the assignment to nextPageToken is asynchronous?

Comment: You have to roll all the code up into the `then` for it to work correctly. Busy waiting around a promise is probably doing more harm than good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `await` operator.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

```
function getApiUrl(nextPageToken) {
    return '<api_url>' + '&playlistId=' + '<playlistId>' + (nextPageToken ? '&pageToken=' + nextPageToken : '');
}

async function getPlaylist() {
    var titles = [],
    nextPageToken = null,
    url = getApiUrl(null);


    // returns new Promise(...)
    nextPageToken = await doRequest(url).nextPageToken;

    url = getApiUrl(nextPageToken);

    // returns empty array
    return titles;
}
```

Comment: `getPlaylist` has to be marked as async

Comment: oh, maybe I was confused. I thought the OP needed to walk multiple pages. I tried to think of a way to integrate async/await into a while loop but couldn't.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are having is that the loop is synchronous but the assignment of nextPageToken is asynchronous. I'm actually not sure, but would something like this work using recursion

```
function getList(url){
    return doRequest(url).then(data => {
        if(data.nextPageToken !== undefined){
            //titles.push()... whatever you're putting into titles
            var nextUrl = getApiUrl(data.nextPageToken);
            return getList(nextUrl);
        }else{
            return;
        }
    });
}
```